# why does css "reset" destroy select optgroup?

Tags: html, css, firefox

found this code in my main css file -- don't know how it got in there or why, but it looks like a reset. The nifty thing is that even though the content is an empty string, it totally munges select optgroups.

check it out:

```css
<style> *::after,
*::before {
  content: '';
}
</style>
```

```html
<select>
  <optgroup label="Swedish Cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="German Cars">
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/des2016/d3e6z3ay/

And, oh fun, it only does this on Firefox.

1. what is this css supposed to do for us?
2. why does it destroy optgroups?

Comment: Indeed, no problems here. Opera and Chrome everything is ok.

Comment: Works for me fine in FF. What version and OS?

Comment: The "Run code snippet" button is not putting the css with the html (probably my fault), but jsfiddle shows it. (FF44 on W10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The * serves to indicate all elements.

The `::before` creates a pseudo-element that is the first child of the element matched and the `::after` pseudo-element matches a virtual last child of the selected element.

It is often used to add cosmetic content to an element by using the content property. This element is inline by default.

The code below put a '' (nothing) before and after all elements.

```
<style> *::after,
*::before {
  content: '';
}
</style>
```

In firefox only what seems to be happing,in this particular case, is that when you put something separating the optgroup you break it element.

Comment: Don't know why this answer was down-voted -- I think it's correct. The last sentence answers part (2) of my question. Looking in the forms.css browser rules (view-source:resource://gre-resources/forms.css) there are two rules with "optgroup > option", so this makes sense.The answer to part (1) is implied in the break-down of the css -- it does not do anything visible, except break certain browser rules unpredictably.

Comment: Me neither, I was surprised when I was voted down. Thanks for your feedback.